# Ingresar un array de strings a un array de formulario [(ngModel)] - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formularios

estoy haciendo un formulario en angular 7 y uno de mis inputs debe contener un `array` de `string`. He definido una clase así:

**model.ts**

```
    export class Oferta {

    constructor(
        public oNombre: string,
        public oTipo: string,
        public oCondiciones: Array<string>,
        public oImagen: string
    ){}

}
```

Luego he definido la clase en el constructor de mi componente de esta manera:

**component.ts**

```
public oferta: Oferta;

constructor() { 
this.oferta = new Oferta('','', [], '')
```

Posterior en el HTML trato de tomar el arreglo pero no me imprime nada

**html**

```
<form name="oferta" #oferta="ngForm">

<input type="hidden" name="oCondiciones" required #oCondiciones="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="oferta.oCondiciones" value="{{condiciones}}">

</form>
```

Mi resultado en consola es este
**Resultado**

```
Oferta {oNombre: "", oTipo: "", oCondiciones: "", oTipo: "" }
oCondiciones: []
oImagen: ""
oNombre: ""
oTipo: ""
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema? Te muestra el arreglo vacío porque no les ingresado datos, sólo lo inicializaste =/

Answer (score 1):

Es lógico que no veas algo representativo ya que es una **estructura** no un dato nativo.

Tienes algunas opciones como iterar el array de condiciones:

```
<input *ngFor="let condition of oferta.oCondiciones; leti = index" [(ngModel)]="oferta.oCondiciones[i]" />
```

Así mismo, si desearas añadir otra condición, en el componente añadirías un string vacío o con un mensaje por defecto:

```
this.oferta.oCondiciones.push('') // y se crearía un input vacío
```

Otra forma que se me ocurre es transformar el array en un string separado por comas y luego hacer uso de un `Array#split` para convertirlo en array:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="unparsedConditions" (ngModelChange)="parseConditions" />
```

Y en tu controlador:

```
parseConditions() {
  this.oferta.oCondiciones = this.unparsedConditions.split(',')
}
```

Cuando cargue el formulario, no olvides convertir el array a string:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.unparsedConditions = this.oferta.oCondiciones.join(',')
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @gugadev me funcionó de maravilla el primer consejo. Ahora tengo otro pequeñito problema. Me pasa los valores sin acentos. Es decir si escribo "promoción" me lo pasa como "promocin". Sabes a qué se debe?